# Create a token for and external API using OpenIddict

Tags: openid-connect, openiddict

My starting point was the Velusia example in the [OpenIddict samples](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/Velusia) and I have successfully logged into this. I'm now experimenting with an external web API by adding a Visual Studio API project to the solution that returns a pseudo weather forecast (*Weather API*).

When I run the solution and log in, the test message can be invoked via the *ResourceController* within the server without error.

Since I don't want an API access token to be stored in the browser because I gather that's bad practice, my plan was to call the *Weather API* by adding a method to the server's aforementioned *ResourceController* to make an HTTP call to the API. The problem is that I get an invalid token, so obviously I'm not generating it correctly.

Here is the code for the method that I added into the *ResourceController*.

```
 [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [HttpGet("weather-forecast")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> WeatherForecast()
        {
        var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Truncated error message...");
            }

        using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost:5003/weatherforecast");
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

        using var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        ...
```

The server's configuration for OpenIddict is:

```
            services.AddOpenIddict()
            .AddCore(options =>                                                                                                                                                                                             
                {
                    options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()                                                                                                                                                               
                           .UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
                })

            .AddServer(options =>                                                                                                                                                                                           
                {
                    options                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                           .SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize")
                           .SetLogoutEndpointUris("/connect/logout")
                           .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token")
                           .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/connect/userinfo")
                           .SetVerificationEndpointUris("/connect/verify")
                           ;

                    options.RegisterScopes(Scopes.Email, Scopes.Profile, Scopes.Roles);                                                                                 

                    options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow();
                    options.AllowClientCredentialsFlow();
                    options.AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

                    options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate().AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();                                                                    
                    options.AddEphemeralEncryptionKey().AddEphemeralSigningKey().DisableAccessTokenEncryption();                                   

                    options.UseAspNetCore()                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration()
                                .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
                                .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
                                .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                                .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough()
                                .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration()
                                .EnableVerificationEndpointPassthrough()
                           ;
                })

            .AddValidation(options =>                                                                                                                                                                                    
                {
                    options.UseLocalServer();                                                                                                                                                                                    
                    options.UseAspNetCore();                                                                                                                                                                                
                });
```

The Weather API startup includes:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
            options.DefaultScheme = OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            });

        // Register the OpenIddict validation components.
        services.AddOpenIddict()
            .AddValidation(options =>
                {
                options.SetIssuer(Common.Urls.stuVelusiaServer);                                                                                       
                 options.SetClientId("testapi");
                 options.SetClientSecret("secret");
                options.UseSystemNetHttp();                                                                                                                            
                options.UseAspNetCore();                                                                                                                            
                options.UseLocalServer();
                });
```

and the Weather API descriptor in the server project is:

```
var descriptor = new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
{
ClientId = "testapi",
ClientSecret = "secret",
ConsentType = OpenIddictConstants.ConsentTypes.Implicit,
DisplayName = "Test API",
Permissions =
    {
    OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode,
    OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Authorization,
    OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Introspection,
    OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Token,
    OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.RefreshToken,
    //OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
    },
Requirements =
    {
        OpenIddictConstants.Requirements.Features.ProofKeyForCodeExchange
    }
};
```

How do I create the correct token for what is a machine-to-machine call? I will need to know the logged-in user's identity (minimum their *subject* or email address) in production projects.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this question? I have the same issue.

Comment: Regrettably not yet.